# This keyword is reserved in vuex

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuex

I have a laravel app with app.js containing:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import { store } from './store/store'

import Sidebar from './Sidebar'

Vue.component('sidebar', Sidebar)    

const app = new Vue({
    store: store,
    el: '#root'
});
```

Store.js contains:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)


export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        menu: ['one', 'two']
    }
});
```

Sidebar  contains:

```
export default {
        computed: {

            routes() {
                return {
                    this.$store.state.menu;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

I run npm run dev and get error "this" is reserved word:

[image: this]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well `return { this.$store.state.menu; }` is a syntax error; what do you intend that to mean?

Comment: Show your webpack config and babelrc please.

Comment: Ha, @Pointy I missed it )))

Comment: It would be either `return this.$store.state.menu;` or `return { "something" : this.$store.state.menu }`

Comment: @Pointy I was looking your comment since you posted it and still took me 4mins to see it :o

Answer (score 0):

```
export default {
        computed: {

            routes() {
                   return this.$store.state.menu;//returning as array
            }
        }
    };
```

or

```
export default {
        computed: {

            routes() {
                   return { 'menu':this.$store.state.menu};//returning as object
            }
        }
    };
```